# BIND10 DNS amplifiaction attack

Tags: domain-name-system

Is BIND 10 authoritative server vulnerable to DNS amplification attacks? If yes, does BIND 10 support RRL and DNS dampening? I tried searching but could find anything good.

Answer (score 3):

BIND 10 is vulnerable for DNS Amplification attacks **if you configure it** to answer all DNS requests regardless from where they are coming or where they are going.

DNS Amplification attack is a result of badly configured DNS (unless you really want an open resolver) servers rather than a vulnerability in the software itself.

Have a read on blogoverflow on how it works: http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/04/about-the-recent-dns-amplification-attack-against-spamhaus-countermeasures-and-mitigation/

Comment: Well, an authoritative server will still amplify just fine - someone using it to amplify just needs to be sending requests for domains that the server is authoritative for, instead of being able to make requests against any domain that an open recursor will answer for.

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach is to not allow recursive requests from outside your network.  That should still be supported by bind 10.  Logging rejected requests may help you to determine an amplification attack is approached.

I use `fail2ban` to temporarily block IP addresses involved in amplification attacks.

The release notes should cover any new or changed functionality.  A quick scan of the [ISC Bind 10 page](http://www.isc.org/downloads/platform/) indicates that there may be and authoritative only configuration which should be relatively resistant to participating in an amplification attack.

EDIT: Amplification attacks use required behavior of a caching name server to direct high volumes of data to a target site.  With few exceptions (OpenDNS, Google DNS, etc.) cached data should not be available to users outside your network.  Best practice is to use split zones or separate DNS servers for internal and external clients.

Depending on your network configuration your DNS cache servers can be used to launch a limited amplification attack withing your network.  Bogon filtering on network segments can limit this capability.

Comment: Just a side note: using fail2ban for blocking IPs that "tries" to amplify DNS traffic is actually likely to be blocking the victim of such attacks, not the offender. Worse: the attacker won't even notice since he's not going to expect an answer anyway

Comment: @Stephane It does what I want.  During the amplification attack, the victim can't directly request data from my server, but can request DNS data via other servers.  I fully realize, the attacker is not expecting a response, but what I want to do is mitigate the attack (DNS replies).  The attacked server will not be able to access my services directly, but I would rather that, than participate in the attack.  Everything goes back to normal when the attack is over.

Comment: That still might not be the best way to protect yourself or the rest of the net: the correct way is, I'm sure you realize, not to answer to queries that results in amplified traffic or require them to be made over TCP. Of course, it's far better to do it that way than simply ignore the problem but, unless you have specific requirements (as you may very well have), it's not the best general-purpose approach.

Comment: @Stephane I am already not responding to the attack with anything but a fail message. `fail2ban` stops the sending of those messages if an attempt to use my server for an amplification attack is detected. What did you think I was doing with fail2ban?